# Can I use Heroku registry as a base image for review app service?

Tags: docker, heroku, deployment, heroku-review-app

One of my Heroku pipelines is currently using Docker deploys (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime) in combination with `heroku.yml` (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-yml-build-manifest).

The review apps are currently building successfully with Docker (on `container` stack). I currently have one `web` and one `worker` service defined in `heroku.yml` and in the 'formation' section of my `app.json`.

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile.web
    worker: Dockerfile.worker
    servicex: Dockerfile.servicex
```

In my review app, I am also trying to run `servicex` which is currently an app hosted on my Heroku with Docker and `container` stack. Since `servicex`'s corresponding app is using Docker, it has an image in Heroku's registry. I am trying to use that image as a base image for `servicex`

```
FROM registry.heroku.com/<app_name>/<process_type>
```

This will work locally since I am authenticated with Heroku's registry, but when the build happens on Heroku it fails with the error:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  5.223MBStep 1/2 : FROM registry.heroku.com/<app_name>/<process_type>
Get https://registry.heroku.com/v2/<app_name>/<process_type>/manifests/latest: no basic auth credentials
```

My question is if I can authenticate with Heroku's registry easily during a build?
If not, what's the best way to go about this. Trying to make any credentials public, and processes from the Dockerfile don't seem to have access to Heroku config credentials.

Answer (score 2):

After speaking with Heroku support, this is not yet possible.

I decided to create a series of base images for our different language stacks, host those on Dockerhub, and use those as a starting point for my review apps' images.

I'm also using a method to cache dependencies in my Dockerfile using a similar strategy here (ruby example using `bundle install` https://medium.com/magnetis-backstage/how-to-cache-bundle-install-with-docker-7bed453a5800)

Since my worker and web services use the same dependencies, the dependency install step uses the cache!